# Ambient occlusion disappear at distance

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Ambient occlusion disappear in blender 2.82, eeve when I get farther from the model, why it is happening this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not the Ambient Occlusion, but the light's shadow distance